# Why ions created in our body doesn't give any sensation of electric shock?

Tags: human-biology

We know almost every cell in human body uses ions specially nerve cells , still why we are not getting shocked by those ions ?

Comment: Curiosity is an excellent thing, if you want to know more about nerve transmission and the general functioning of the nervous system, you're going to need to do some research on your own. By all means ask questions here, but once you've done some research yourself and understand a bit more about what it is you're asking. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nervous_system) on the subject has lots of background and many links to follow, I'm sure you'll find it very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Quite apart from the fact that those ionic potentials are what we feel WITH, they're on the order of 70-80 millivolts.  Would you expect to be shocked by say a common 1.5 volt battery?  Or even the 12 volts of an ordinary car battery? Even the ordinary sort of static electricity shock, such as you might feel from stroking a cat on a dry day, can be thousands of volts.

Comment: Hi , I also want to know how this ionic small electrical signals transforms into a something sensible , like light, sound, touch etc . We don't feel any current , we feel colors , cry of a baby etc . Why is that?

Comment: @Koushik Pal: The only real answer is that nobody really knows.  We know a good bit about how stimuli - light, sound, pressure, &c - get transformed into nerve impulses (which BTW aren't really electrical signals, they're waves of membrane depolarization along nerve fibers), but almost nothing (AFAIK, anyway) about how the brain converts them into the various qualia that we experience.  It's a queston that exists in the terra incognita between neurobiology and philosophy.  As for feeling current, ask how the 1.1-1.5 volt currents of your CPU got transformed to this text :-)